# How to transform EF Objects to WCF Models using Repository pattern

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, wcf, repository-pattern

I'm trying to build my first (Rest?) WCF service on .NET with entity framework 6 following Repository pattern.

So it is supposed that I have to expose only simple object from the service, not the  entire EF classes, right?

So I build a simple Model Like this, that represent some field from a database table:

```
[DataContract]
public class FormasPagoModel
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string FormaPago { get; set; }        
}
```

This is the data type  returned by my WCF service method. So I whant a method GetbyID on my service. To do so, i create an interface:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T:class
{
    T GetEntityByID(int Key);
}
```

and a Repository abstract class:

```
public abstract class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    protected readonly OhmioNETEntities context = new OhmioNETEntities();

    public T GetEntityByID(int Key)
    {         
        return context.Set<T>().Find(Key);
    }
}
```

and a concrete implementation (ANX_FormasPago is my EF Class that is linked to a database table):

```
public class FormasPagoRep : Repository<ANX_FormasPago>
{
}
```

Finally my WCF Service class

```
public class WCFService
{
    public FormasPagoModel FormasPago_GetbyID(int Key)
    {            
        ANX_FormasPago EFEntity = new FormasPagoRep().GetEntityByID(Key);

        return new FormasPagoModel
        {
            ID = EFEntity.ID_FormaPago,
            FormaPago = EFEntity.FormaPago,
        };
    }
}
```

As you can see, internally I get an EF class of type ANX_FormasPago and transform it to FormasPagoModel. Of course if I need for instance FormasPago_Save, i need to write the exact oposite code that is transform my Model(FormasPagoModel) to EF class(ANX_FormasPago)

With this code, I end up having, for each database table:

> A) An EF class.
>
> B) A Simplified Model class.
>
> C) A concrete Repository.
>
> D) A WCF Service method for each method.

So, I'm I in the right path here? Or am i just complicating things up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you're almost there. In my opinion you are actually missing one layer (*Business logic*). It's not the responsibility of your WCF service to get data from repository and convert it to a different type. The reason is that in many cases the creation of the final model object can be much more complex. I wouldn't like to clutter the WCF service with that.

Ideally the architecture would look like that:

> WCF --> Business Logic --> Repository --> Entity Framework

Every layer can only talk to the layer **directly** on it's **right**.

- *Repository* returns filtered EF entities
- *Business* processes them (can use multiple repositories, perform calculations and other stuff)
- *Business* returns simple DTO objects (*Business* should not reference WCF)
- *WCF* grabs DTOs and maps them to *WCF* models (I'd use [AutoMApper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper/) for that btw). This mapping is necessary as *Business* doesn't reference *WCF* components (DataContract and DataMember attributes are not accessible in *Business*).
- *WFC* releases models to the web

Also I wouldn't bother to have an abstract / base / generic repository. Sooner or later you'll end up having some ugly workarounds to handle not compatible entities ([Refused bequest](https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/refused-bequest) problem).

Ultimately you'll end up having even more classes than you proposes, but each of them will have [single responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). They'll be simpler, easier to test and more reusable (e.g. you can replace WCF layer and use WPF or MVC instead without touching different layers).

Comment: Excelent Answer! Thnak you. Even if i don't fully understand all that you wrote i will put my hands to work. Can I ask you some futher questions about your model? thanks again!

Comment: Glad I could help. Sure, go ahead

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but i'm re-reading what you propose and some doubt came up. You say that Business layer return simple DTOs. and WCF map them to WCF models. Does that mean that i need to create two identical models, one to return from business and one to send with WCF?

Comment: That way I need One repository object for each EF class, one business class and one WCF class and I need to auto map back and foward between them. That's a LOT of code!

Comment: @ericpap This is the cost of a good architecture. If you called Entity Famework right form WCF, you wouldn't even have the repository layer. There would be less code, but everything would be tangled. The logic layer should not be WCF specific. This way you can easily replace WCF with anything else, without even touching the logic layer. Good separation also helps when you write unit tests. If you're just making a school project or sth like that, I wouldn't bother to work so much on architecture, however if it's en enterprise software it really helps in maintenance.

Comment: Thanks for that. I understand your point, and its perfectly logical for a enteprise production software like mine. I modify my model according to your sugest. Two more questions: 1) You said that Business Model have to be different from WCF model? Is there a reason for that? They will be exactly the same. What I have done is put all my models in a separate assembly (call models) that I reference from all the other layers including client. They contain the DataContract Tag and I use them to return data from Business, and to send data with WCF Service. Do you see a problem here?

Comment: And 2) From what I have read, I shouldn't use the "add service" in the client because they create automatic proxys. So as I already have a separate assembly for my models, I could also use a separate assembly for the WCF contract and Service class and reference it on client manually... Do you recommend that? Thank you very much again

Comment: @ericpap 1) The problem is that in order to use DataContract attribute you need to directly reference WCF in your model project. Than by referencing the model project in business you contaminate the business with WCF specific dependencies, which is bad in general. The WCF and logic models won't be the same - WCF has additional attributes. 2)  It depends. Generally I'm not a big fan of auto-proxies. So If both systems are developed simultaneously I'd reference it in the client manually. If I'm supposed to integrate with something that is already big and complex, I'd go for auto-proxies.